# ESLint throws an error when trying to assign multiple variables to the same value

Tags: javascript, eslint

Why does ESLint throw a `Parsing error: Unexpected token ,` after `a` variable declaration on this line of code?

`const a, b, c = 1;`

My `.eslintrc.json` looks like this;

```
{

    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jquery": true,
        "commonjs": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "script"
    },
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "quotes": ["error", "double"]
    }

}
```

Comment: Because it doesn't like serial assignment. You can change the rules if you like.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Try copying and pasting `const a, b, c = 1;` into a console. I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's invalid in JS and you can't just change the rules of JavaScript...

Comment: Oops. Read that wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that in JS.

If multiple variables listed in a variable declaration (either `var`, `let` or `const`), each value has its own initializer, so it's impossible to assign a single value to multiple variables in a single declaration statement, without repetition.

If an initializer is missing (no *`= value`* part present), the variable will be set to `undefined`.

So if you used `let`, then `c` would become `1`, while `a` and `b` would be `undefined`:

```js
let a, b, c = 1;

console.log(a, b, c) //undefined undefined 1
```

However, omitting the initializer in a `const` declaration throws an error (it doesn't make too much sense to assign `undefined` to a constant, right?)

Therefore, your code fails (not just in ESLint, but in any JS runtime that correctly implements the ECMAScript standard):

```js
const a, b, c = 1; //SyntaxError
```

To assign the same value to multiple variables, you have to either:

- Repeat the value (this won't work if the value is an object literal (including array literals and function expressions) or returned by a constructor, a factory, or non-pure function):

  ```js
  const a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

  console.log(a, b, c) //1 1 1
  ```
- Assign the variables from each other (tip: put the one with the shortest name first and repeat that one):

  ```js
  const a = 1, b = a, c = a;

  console.log(a, b, c) //1 1 1
  ```
- Use `let`:

  ```js
  let a, b, c;
  a = b = c = 1

  console.log(a, b, c) //1 1 1
  ```
- Destructure an infinite iterator (that seems useful in case of a very large number of variables):

  ```js
  const [a, b, c] = (function*(v){while(true) yield v})(1);
                                                     // ^--- Value

  console.log(a, b, c) //1 1 1
  ```